Google OAuth Refresh Token Expires After 1 Hour (PHP Google Ads API with Laravel)
My Google OAuth refresh token expires after one hour, even though both my OAuth and Google Ads API applications are verified and approved.

Both OAuth and Google Ads API apps are verified and approved.
Created a new client_credentials.json file after approval.
Using the provided Laravel example for the PHP Google Ads API.
Added the developer token with basic access and populated clientId and clientSecret in the google_ads_php.ini file.

For the refresh token i used command ~/go/bin/oauth2l fetch --credentials CLIENT_SECRET.json --scope adwords to obtain a refresh token.
And added this token to google_ads_php.ini too.
Despite these steps, I consistently encounter a "token has been expired or revoked" error after 60 minutes.

please edit your question and include [example]

This is standard oauth practice access tokens expire after one hour. Its up to the developer to use a refresh token request a new access token when the access token expires.
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());

